# Ms sql Inner Join order error

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, join

Hi i have problem about inner join order i am creating sql query dynamic in c#
but when the code runs the out put is

```
select p.CategoryId,p.Name,[dbo].CampaignProduct.CampaignId,
[dbo].CampaignProduct.ProductId,[dbo].Category.Name 
from CampaignProduct 
inner join Category ON p.CategoryId=Category.Id
 Inner join Campaign ON CampaignProduct.CampaignId=Campaign.Id 
 Inner join Product p ON CampaignProduct.ProductId=p.Id
```

but this query cant work. But when i change this to

```
select p.CategoryId,p.Name,[dbo].CampaignProduct.CampaignId,[dbo].CampaignProduct.ProductId,[dbo].Category.Name 
from CampaignProduct 
 Inner join Product p ON CampaignProduct.ProductId=p.Id
inner join Category ON p.CategoryId=Category.Id
 Inner join Campaign ON CampaignProduct.CampaignId=Campaign.Id
```

so my problem is inner join order is there any chance to resolve this ? or i have to code the order inner join?

my code block

```
string qry = "";
            string select = "select ";
            string from = " from ";
            string firstfrom = "";
            string inners = "";
            var res=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<QueryCreatorType>>(data);

            foreach (var item in res)
            {
                select += $"[dbo].{item.Table}.{item.Column},";
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(firstfrom))
                {
                    firstfrom += $" {item.Table}";
                }
                 if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Parent))
                {

                    inners += $" Inner join {item.Parent} ON {item.Table}.{item.Column}={item.Parent}.Id";

                }



            }

            qry = select + from+firstfrom+inners;
```

Comment: Remember to name your joins with alias. Its good practice

Comment: i know that but it does not change anything thank you.

Comment: `or i have to code the order inner join?` Yes.

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: The problem is i am creating query in c# from a request. But i cant handle order cause i do not know which must be before. as you see first code block does not work . Cause order but second block is working which i have  edit it Manuel.

Comment: If you need help with the code that generates the query, it seems you should add that code to your question. Maybe I'm stating the obvious but your app will need to generate the join order to avoid forward references.

Comment: Why are you creating dynamic SQL in C#? Use a stored procedure or parametrised SQL. Creating dynamic SQL is asking for injection.

Comment: @Larnu That depends on the nature of the dynamic SQL. The above query, for example, is not open to injection.

Comment: @mjwills I'd agree, but considering that the OP is, somehow, generating the tables dynamically (hence why the `JOIN`s are being generated in the wrong order), then this seems to imply that they could be doing a lot of things we're not aware of (which **could** be open to injection).

Answer (score 0):

Here a little testable example:

```
--drop table CampaignProduct
--drop table Campaign
--drop table Product
--drop table Category
--GO

create table CampaignProduct(CampaignId int, ProductId int)
create table Campaign(Id int, Name varchar(100))
create table Product(Id int, Name varchar(100), CategoryId int)
create table Category(Id int, Name varchar(100))
GO

insert into Category values
(1,'Eletronics'),
(2,'Footwear'),
(3,'Toys')

insert into Product values
(1,'Tablet',1),
(2,'Cheap Radio',1),
(3,'Television',1),
(4,'Cheap Jogging Tenis',2),
(5,'Bazillian leather boot',2),
(6,'Red Prada for Rich Woman',2),
(7,'Overexpensive Plastic Doll',3),
(8,'Overexpensive Plastic Action Movie Action Figure',3),
(9,'Cheap Yo-Yo',3)

insert into Campaign values
(1, 'Eletronics Sales'),
(2, 'For all ages girls'),
(3, 'Cheap stuff')

insert into CampaignProduct values
(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),
(2,1),(1,6),(1,7),
(3,2),(1,4),(1,9)

GO
```

Below a more organized way to write your query

```
select 
 pr.CategoryId
,pr.Name
,cp.CampaignId
,cp.ProductId
,ct.Name 
from Product pr
 join Category ct On pr.CategoryId = ct.Id
 join CampaignProduct cp On cp.ProductId = pr.Id
 join Campaign cm On cm.Id = cm.Id
```

Below you working example

```
select 
 p.CategoryId
,p.Name
,[dbo].CampaignProduct.CampaignId
,[dbo].CampaignProduct.ProductId
,[dbo].Category.Name 
from CampaignProduct 
 Inner join Product p ON CampaignProduct.ProductId=p.Id
 inner join Category ON p.CategoryId=Category.Id
 Inner join Campaign ON CampaignProduct.CampaignId=Campaign.Id
```

Below you **not** working example

```
--select
-- p.CategoryId
--,p.Name
--,[dbo].CampaignProduct.CampaignId
--,[dbo].CampaignProduct.ProductId
--,[dbo].Category.Name 
--from CampaignProduct 
-- inner join Category ON p.CategoryId=Category.Id
-- Inner join Campaign ON CampaignProduct.CampaignId=Campaign.Id 
-- Inner join Product p ON CampaignProduct.ProductId=p.Id
```

The example above don't works because at the

```
 inner join Category ON p.CategoryId=Category.Id
```

the alias p is not defined yet so parser don't knows it meanings note even you put Products that table was not mentioned yet (it's on a below join) and thus will not be recognized.

Also to begginers: SQL is not a procedural language like (Java, C#, PHP), you is merely declaring how those tables relates with each another and asking for the result of a dataset "function". The order of how records are fetched is not of your concern and the engine will do it as it guess is the optimal way based in indexes, heuristcs, statistics, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add some validation to check if any tables the current item is dependent on have been added to the sql; if not then add them before you add the current item.  You may find it easier to pre sort them into an ordered list before looping round to build the sql.

```
var ordered = new List<QueryCreatorType>();
foreach (var item in res)
{
    if (!ordered.Any(x => x.Table == item.Parent.Table))
    {
        ordered.Add(item.Parent);
    }
    ordered.Add(item);
}
```

Note - I've not tested this code but it should get you started.  You may want to Google it as there is probably better examples of this sort of code on the Internet somewhere.

As others have suggested then building the SQL on the fly does open you up to SQL injection and you should validate the items you are using.